# Javascript-JQuery: sliding menu going left-to-right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I have a piece of text put outside of the browser and I want it to appear when the cursor hovers over another piece of text. Here's my code:

**HTML file**

```
<div class="panel_help">
        <div class="help_text">
            <h4>Τι κάνω?</h4>
            <p>This is the text that is hidden and needs to appear...</p>
        </div>
        <p class="slide_help"><strong>Show text</strong></p>
    </div>
```

**CSS file**

```
  .help_text {
    color: aliceblue;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    right: -9em;
    top: 6em;
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}

.slide_help {
    color: aliceblue;
    right: 10px;
    top: 4.5em;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

**JS file**

```
$(".panel_help").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".help_text").animate({right: "1.5em"},'slow');
        $(".slide_help").animate({right: "9em"}, 'slow');
});

$(".panel_help").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".help_text").animate({right: "-9em"},'slow');
    $(".slide_help").animate({right: "1em"}, 'slow');
});
```

The problem is that sometimes it takes two animations to stop, so it goes left-right-left-right, and then stops! Am I doing something wrong? I'm very new to JQuery... Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a working example of the issue we could see?

Comment: Have a look at the [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)-function. `$('selector').stop().animate()`. This might help you

Comment: Added some more code, I think that should be enough...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the JavaScript / jQuery and use CSS.

```
.help_text {
    right: -9em;
}
.slide_help {
    right: 1em; 
}

.help_text, .slide_help {
    -webkit-transition: right 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: right 0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: right 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: right 0.4s linear;
    transition: right 0.4s linear;
}

.panel_help:hover .help_text {
    right: 1.5em;
}

.panel_help:hover .slide_help {
    right: 9em;
}
```

This way you don't use the jQuery Events, which sometimes don't work properly

Answer (score 2):

Just add `.stop()` before `animate(...)` to stop your current animation:

```
$('.panel_help').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.help_text').stop().animate({right: '1.5em'}, 'slow');
    $('.slide_help').stop().animate({right: '9em'}, 'slow');
});

$('.panel_help').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.help_text').stop().animate({right: '-9em'}, 'slow');
    $('.slide_help').stop().animate({right: '1em'}, 'slow');
});
```

[.stop() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to finish the animation when the mouse leave the area. If not, the animation won't stop.

Try to put stop() before init every animation:

`$(".help_text").stop().animate({right: "1.5em"},'slow');
$(".slide_help")stop().animate({right: "9em"}, 'slow');`